# Install language pack + Set UI language powershell

Tags: windows, windows-10-desktop

im trying to install and use a new language in Windows 10 1809 with powershell.

I'm installing the language pack using:

```
Add-WindowsPackage -Online -PackagePath .\lp_de.cab
```

After the installation is done, i'm try to set the language of the whole windows 10 using:

```
Set-Culture de-DE
Set-WinUILanguageOverride -Language de-DE
```

After that i reboot the system, the language is not set. I have to redo the last commando's and then have to sign out again.

So after an installation of a language pack, does the system really have to reboot to use it? Or am i missing something?

Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use these commands  to install and set your language :

`Add-WindowsPackage -Online -PackagePath .\lp_de.cab`

`$ll = New-WinUserLanguageList -Language $language`

`Set-WinUserLanguageList $ll -Force`

Note that $language would be the language code you want to apply (after the previous install)

And if you want to be sure, you can use  `(GET-WinSystemLocale).Name` to check if your language is installed.